# Django accessing OneToOneField

Tags: python, django, model

Made a view that extended User:

```
class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='user')

    def __unicode__(self):
          return "%s" % (self.user)
```

I am currently trying to access the User model by accessing the Client object. At the moment I am getting an error in the python shell:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10:
```

I know it has something to do with accessing an OneToOneField but I don't know why. All the solutions I found were from the perspective of the User model and not the extended Client, in my case.

To make it abit clearer. Whenever I access the User.

```
>>> client1 = User.objects.get(username="client1")
>>> client1.user
>>> client1.user.attribute
```

It echos the attributes of the extended Model, in this case the Client attribute. How can I achieve this the other way around. So through the Client model instead of the User model.

Comment: What is the offending code?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with Django, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861594/python-3-3-programming-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-be

Comment: client1 = Client.objects.get(user="client_1")

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you need to pass the user object and not a string.

```
client1 = User.objects.get(username="client_1") # this is the user object
client_obj = Client.objects.get(user=client1) # pass object NOT STRING
```

you can also do this: (assuming the user's id is given)

```
client1 = Client_objects.get(user__id=1) # pass the user's id instead
```

I hope it works ;)

Comment: Thank you! As you can see I just edited my question before your answer. Seems the best work around!

Comment: Note that the same can be done in a single query: `Client.objects.get(user__username="client_1")`. Use `.select_related('user')` if you know you want to access the `User` object's data as well.