# django check if user is allowed to add Post

Tags: django, django-users

i am creating a blog just for practice and i want to allow **some users** to add/delete a post how to add this BooleanField to users and check if allowed in templates

Comment: Django comes with a [permissions system](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#topic-authorization). You should give your users `add_post` and `delete_post` permissions (or add them to a group that has those permissions), rather than trying to add a new boolean field to your model.

Comment: thank you but how to check them in templates is it {% if user.allowed%}....

Comment: There are many tutorials and documentations about this, quick google: [Django Tutorial Part 8: User authentication and permissions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Server-side/Django/Authentication). Search for `Permissions` on that page, and you'll jump right into the permissions part in the models and how to check them in your templates. Not satisfied? [google](https://www.google.nl/search?q=django+permissions+template&oq=django+permissions+template&aqs=chrome.0.0l2j69i64l3.5679j0j7&client=ubuntu&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: The page I linked to shows you how, in the [authentication data in templates](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/auth/default/#authentication-data-in-templates) section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like what you are talking about is an extension beyond the default user auth.  Something like this should work:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

PERMS = (('E', 'Editor'),('P', 'Poster'),...)
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    my_custom_permission_levels = modelsCharField(max_length=1, choices=PERMS)
    ...
```

And you could access consistent with this post - [Django accessing OneToOneField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22579605/django-accessing-onetoonefield)

```
profile = Profile.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

And add that to the context to access in the template.