# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'n'

Tags: python, django

Error: ValueError at /followed/n/

Actually i don't get why this error appear, i've tried using int() and float() but, anything seems to work

**views.py**

```
def followed(request, follow_to):
    return render(request, "test.html",{'following':Following.objects.get(follow_to=follow_to),
        'selfieList':Selfie.objects.filter(selfie_user=follow_to),})
```

**template**

```
{% for f in following %}
        <a href="{% url 'followed' f.follow_to %}">{{f.follow_to}}</a> <br>
    {% endfor %}
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^followed/(?P<follow_to>[-\w]+)/$', followed, name='followed'),
```

**models.py**

```
class Following(models.Model):
    follow_from = models.ForeignKey("auth.User",related_name='from_person')
    follow_to = models.ForeignKey("auth.User", related_name='to_person')
    date_follow = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.follow_from)

    def __str__(self):
```

Comment: Which line is the error from?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django invalid literal for int() with base 10](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23394545/django-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: Can you post the code of form where you are submitting the request as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have problem with this piece of code in your view.

```
Following.objects.get(follow_to=follow_to)
```

Here the `follow_to` parameter passed to view is string and from the url mentioned it seems it is `'n'`. But you are searching for foreign key which will search for `id` of an object. `id` is integer.

So in the query its trying to convert `'n'` into `int` to search appropriate object. But the conversion fails.

You need to either check for that and/or use `id` related regex in url for `follow_to` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

If the `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model is used, its `pk` is an integer. However, the url pattern matches any word character (`\w`). Thus if only numbers should be allowed, modifying `urls.py` to only allow integer id matches might be a solution.

```
url(r'^followed/(?P<follow_to>\d+)/$', followed, name='followed'),
```