# Issues with string and integers as multiple conditions in while loop? (python)

Tags: python

I'm a beginner in the language python and have occurred some issues writing code containing a while loop which i want to check multiple conditions with one of the conditions not being checked and issues with strings/integers.

The original code (2nd code sample) was what I first wrote but the issue with it was that after a key met the condition of the first loop it would move on to the second loop so that if i entered nothing into the program when its running it will just come up with an error instead of please enter a key. The only way i could think of to fix this was to alter the code so it checks for one of multiple conditions with one while loop. But i had some issues with the variable key for each condition being a different type (integer/string) and it wasn't fixed when i attempted to use int() and str(). Besides that the code doesn't seem to check for all of the conditions. A major drawback of the altered code is that it will no longer tell the user what exactly they did wrong e.g. didn't enter anything, entered a character that's not a number

The Code:

```
def Key(key):
    while len(key) < 1 or key.isalpha() == True or ((key > 25) or (key < -25)):
        print("The key must be a number between numbers 26 and -26")
        key = int(input("What is the key: "))
    print (key)

key = input("What is the key: ")
Key(key)
```

The Original Code:

```
def Key(key):
    while len(key) < 1:
        print("Please enter a key")
        key = int(input("What is the key: "))
    while key.isalpha() == True :
        print("Please enter a number!")
        key = int(input("What is the key: "))
    key=int(key)
    while (key > 25) or (key < -25):
        print("The key must be in between numbers 26 and -26")
        key = int(input("What is the key: "))
    print key

key = input("What is the key: ")
Key(key)
```

Any help, improvements and better way of doing this would be extremely helpful
Sorry for the ridiculously long post
Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

Problem lies here while taking input from user. key is expecting an int but if you enter `characters` it will fail. remove `(int(...))` while taking the input

```
while len(key) < 1:
     print("Please enter a key")
     key = int(input("What is the key: "))
```

If you run the code in `try...except`, you will find this error

[Python 3.3 programming. ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861594/python-3-3-programming-valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10-be)

[Demo](http://ideone.com/FeSDYL) of your working code

Comment: You are aware that this code does not work as intended? Imagine one enters as key 'a', which fulfils the condition len(key) < 1 of the first loop. This will end up stuck in the second loop, since its not a number. However the previous precondition (len(key) < 1) will not be checked any further in the program and hence the error message print("Please enter a key") won't be shown.

Comment: @DJanssens this is OP's code. I am just explaining where its wrong. If you click on Demo, you will see updated code

Answer (score 0):

Programmers should be lazy.  The good kind of lazy.  For instance follow the „Don't Repeat Yourself“ principle (DRY) and don't repeat data and/or code like the call and prompt for asking the user for a key.

Python has no DO … WHILE kind of loop, so this is usually written as an ”endless” loop which is left with `break` or `return` when the right condition is met.

```
def ask_for_key(lower_limit=-25, upper_limit=25):
    while True:
        try:
            result = int(raw_input('What is the key: '))
        except ValueError:
            pass  # Intentionally ignored.
        else:
            if lower_limit <= result <= upper_limit:
                return result
        print 'The key must be a number between {0} and {1}'.format(
            lower_limit, upper_limit
        )
```

Answer (score -1):

As you described yourself, there were some major problems with your original code. Namely the fact that you could pass a specific test, but later in a further while loop you could still end up with an incorrect input which was "checked' in a previous while loop.

Checking it all together is a good idea. I'd suggest to use a check function that checks if the key fits or not. It returns `True` if it does and `False` if it doesn't. This way you won't repeat yourself over and over and just need one while loop that keeps checking the input until it's correct.

Something like:

```
def check_key(key):
    if len(key) < 1:
        print("Please enter a key")
        return False
    if key.isalpha() == True :
        print("Please enter a number!")
        return False
    if (int(key) > 25) or (int(key) < -25):
        print("The key must be in between numbers 26 and -26")
        return False
    return True

def main():
    key = raw_input("What is the key: ")
    while check_key(key) == False:
        key = raw_input("What is the key: ")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: I'm wondering why I got a down vote, OP asked for a solution that was able to output different error messages, so the user knows what went wrong.