# user_logged_in_handler() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given) in django

Tags: python, django

i have the following views.py:

```
from django.template import loader
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from student.models import CustomUser
from student.forms import UserForm
from django.template.context_processors import csrf
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.auth.signals import user_logged_in
from .models import UserSession

def user_logged_in_handler(sender,request,CustomUser,**kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=CustomUser,
        session_id= request.session.session_key
        )
user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler)

def delete_user_sessions(CustomUser):
    user_sessions=UserSession.objects.filter(user=CustomUser)
    for user_session in user_sessions:
        user_session.session.delete()
```

i have the following models.py:

```
class UserSession(models.Model):
user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

Also in models.py i have class CustomUser(AbstractUser). What's wrong in my views.py as the error says when i try to access /admin/

```
user_logged_in_handler() takes exactly 3 arguments (2 given)
```

The full models.py is as follows:
//models.py

```
from django.utils import timezone
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session

class CustomUser(AbstractUser):


    addr1= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    addr2= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    city= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    state= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    country= models.CharField(max_length=20,choices=country_choices)
    pincode= models.IntegerField(default=0,blank=True,null=True)
    securityq= models.CharField(max_length=20)
    securitya= models.CharField(max_length=20)

class userresp(models.Model):

    uid=models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL,blank=True,null=True)
    resp=models.CharField(max_length=20)
    datetime=models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"{} {}".format(self.uid,self.datetime)

    class Meta:
        db_table="userresp"

class UserSession(models.Model):
    user= models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    session=models.ForeignKey(Session)
```

Comment: Django version?

Comment: version 1.8 ...

Answer (score 0):

As you have a `CustomUser` model, you need to register it as the sender.

```
def user_logged_in_handler(sender,request, user, **kwargs):
    UserSession.objects.get_or_create(
        user=user,
        session_id= request.session.session_key
    )
user_logged_in.connect(user_logged_in_handler, sender=CustomUser)
```

Check more details in [Django auth signal doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.signals.user_logged_in)

Comment: now it gives this error...Cannot assign "<class 'student.models.CustomUser'>": "UserSession.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance.

Comment: still the above error...ValueError at /admin/login/.....Cannot assign "<class 'student.models.CustomUser'>": "UserSession.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance

Comment: Updated again. This should work. I missed the user instance before.

Comment: UserSession.user" must be a "CustomUser" instance - >user=(should be an instance of CustomUser)...how do i do that?

Comment: now this error...invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'iie27cmjouht24y424g44s5qlm999vcj'

Comment: Seems like it's not related to the issue. There might be something else.

Comment: what do you mean?

Comment: Maybe somewhere in the code, you are trying to keep some other data type value in an integer field. Check this question for more details - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861594/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10

Comment: The new error you are getting is being caused by this line `session_id= request.session.session_key`, the value is not `int`