# Python 3 sum 2 integers with input. ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1'

Tags: python, input, sum

I am trying to add 2 integers in Python3 using input.

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x+y
a = int(input("Enter first number"))
b = int(input("Enter second number"))
print("The sum of a and b is", sum(a,b))
```

and get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "Main.py", line 7, in <module>
a = int(input("Enter first number"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '1 1'
```

Another concern is this works normally in my Jupyter notebook,
but for another online practice center it shows this error.

Comment: What is the input you are giving? It looks like you are trying to convert `'1 1'` to an `int`.

Comment: the first step in debugging should be to split `int(input(..))` into two statements so that you can examine the result of `input(..)` to see if it's what you are assuming it is.

Comment: You are not giving the right input mate.

Giving input as 1 1 as Tomothy said, would obviously give you this error. Because Python is converting this input of 1 1 into integer and it can convert '11' to int but not '1 1'. Of course it's supposed to give this error.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13861594/valueerror-invalid-literal-for-int-with-base-10)

Comment: @Tomothy32 The practice center is providing that input, it looks like two space separated integers?

Is that a problem with this code?

Comment: @AmitAmola The practice center inputs into my code, I don't think this is a duplicate of the other question as it is not a float number is it?

Comment: If you see below that float answer, the answerer does mention about spaces as well. That's why I marked it as a duplicate. 

Now see, if the input is going to be like that only, then you can use .replace(" ","") and this would work perfectly fine I believe.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working, but not for the specific input the practice center is giving. Make this modification:

```
nums = [int(x) for x in input("Enter numbers: ").split()]
print("The sum of a and b is", sum(nums))
```

By the way, `sum` is a built-in function, so you don't have to write it yourself. The only line that really changed is this:

```
nums = [int(x) for x in input("Enter numbers: ").split()]
```

`nums` will be a list of numbers, as the name implies. The next part is the list comprehension. `input("Enter numbers: ").split()` will take the input and split it on any whitespace. For instance, `'hello world'` will be turned into a list with `['hello', 'world']`. In this case, `'1 1'` will be turned into a list with `['1', '1']`. Then, with the list comprehension, you are turning each element into an integer (`['1', '1']` -> `[1, 1]`). Then, you pass this list into `sum`. Also, this does the same thing as the list comprehension:

```
nums = list(map(int, input("Enter numbers: ").split()))
```

It doesn't matter which one you choose. If you wanted to get real fancy, you can do the whole thing in one line:

```
print("The sum of a and b is", sum(map(int, input("Enter numbers: ").split())))
```

Answer (score 0):

Given that your input are coming with spaces itself, you can use replace command and replace those spaces.

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x+y

a = int(input("Enter first number: ").replace(" ",""))
b = int(input("Enter second number: ").replace(" ",""))
print("The sum of a and b is: ", sum(a,b))
```

For your specific case, this should work. What I am doing here is that I am converting the input like '8 3 525 5', to '835255', which itself will be easily converted to int later on and will work perfectly.

Removing the duplicate as well mate.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to input all values in the same line as **1 1**, then you should use `split()`:

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x+y

a, b = map(int, input("Enter numbers ").strip().split())
print("The sum of a and b is", sum(a,b))
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py xxx.py
Enter numbers 1 1
The sum of a and b is 2
```

If separately values need to be inputted:

```
def sum(x,y):
    return x+y

a = int(input("Enter first number ").strip())
b = int(input("Enter second number ").strip())

print("The sum of a and b is", sum(a,b))
```

**Output:**

```
C:\Users\Desktop>py xxx.py
Enter numbers 1 1
The sum of a and b is 2
```